# Index in the Select projection

Tags: c#, linq, select, ienumerable

I would like my index to start from a number count greater than 0 while doing something like this:

```
var dataSource = WebConfigurationHelper.GetSupportedDomainsString().Select((domain, index) => 
new { index , Name = domain });
```

so my output becomes:

```
index=2 domain=zombieland
index=3 domain=mydomain
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can adjust it in the Select projection:

```
var dataSource = WebConfigurationHelper.GetSupportedDomainsString()
     .Select((domain, index) =>  new { Index = index + 2, Name = domain });
```

The reason my original suggestion of `new { index + 2, Name = domain }` wouldn't work is that a *projection initializer* (where you specify just an expression, and let the compiler infer the name) only works when the expression is a "simple name", a "member access" or a "base access".

Comment: I almost felt very stupid for asking, but no I had tried that - I get "Invalid anonymous type member decorator" squigly line error but then this worked:   var dataSource = WebConfigurationHelper.GetSupportedDomainsString().Select((domain, index) => 
                new { Index = index + 2, Name = domain });

Comment: @Max Malygin: The compiler won't infer a name from `index + 2` for you; you have to explicitly name the member.